# Accessing variable name

Tags: ruby

I trying to some parameter validation outside of Rails.

```
def create_statement(action, ...)
  valid_one_of(action, ['ADD', 'MOVE', 'DELETE'])
  ...
end
```

Validation Method:

```
def valid_one_of(input, valid_values)
  return true if valid_values.include?(input)
  raise "#{input} was not a valid value for #{input.var_name}" 
end
```

Sample Call:

```
create_statement('Bob')
```

So the output would be:

```
Bob was not valid value for action
```

The problem how do i get **input.var_name** ?

---

I for a workaround I could pass

```
valid_one_of(action, ['ADD', 'MOVE', 'DELETE'], 'action')
```

(and use 3rd parm for my output) but this doesn't seem feels bit redundant.

If its not possible to access variable name is there a more DRY coding style than this workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to get the name of a local variable, and even if you could,  which name would you want?  The name of the parameter as define on the method definition?  the name of the variable in the caller?

I don't think your "work-around" is that horrible,  but I could suggest a couple of slight variations that might read a little better.

Also I am not sure if your intent is to actually pass in the list of valid values at the call site, or if you might have, say a hash of valid values that you might use the passed in type to look up the valid values from.

```
def valid_one_of_type type, input:, valid_values:
  return true if valid_values.include?(input)
  raise "#{input} was not a valid value for #{type}" 
end

my_action = "bob"

valid_one_of_type :action , input: my_action, valid_values: ['ADD', 'MOVE', 'DELETE'] 

def valid_one_of_type type, input, valid_values
  return true if valid_values.include?(input)
  raise "#{input} was not a valid value for #{type}" 
end

my_action = "bob"

valid_one_of_type :action , my_action, ['ADD', 'MOVE', 'DELETE']
```

Another option would be to wrap your actions in a class and do the validations on creation:

```
class Action 
  VALID_ACTIONS = ['ADD', 'MOVE', 'DELETE']
  def initialize action
    unless VALID_ACTIONS.include? action 
      raise "#{action} is not a valid value for #{self.class.name}"
    end
  end
end

my_action = Action.new "bob"
```

Comment: I would want the name of in the caller (In this case 'action' not 'input')

I would prefer lighter weight solution then creating an class for each of my parameters; in this case I have ~6 parms I would like to validate.... creating new classes I think would distract from the main intent of code.
 - Thanks for the ideas